# Unknown representation of number as bits

Tags: algorithms

I am self taught in CS and came across this while looking at binary search applied to multiplication. I don't understand this part:
OK, we have some x that has binary representation $10110010(1*2 + 1*2^4 + 1*2^5 + 1^7$) ...I understand this, but don't know what following means $x = 2^4(1011) + 0010$. What is name of second notation, where can I find more about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a bit more context is needed. The $2^4$ is not the same as the 1011 in the parenthesis in any common number system. Maybe here it is just multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've split an 8-bit byte into two four-bit **nibbles** (sometimes spelled "nybble").  The brackets denote multiplication; it's just saying that
$$10110010 = 10000\times 1011 + 0010\,,$$
(written all in binary to avoid having two different bases in the same expression).  This is just like saying, in decimal, that
$$837\,487 = 1000\times837+487\,.$$
There isn't really anything to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you understand it better if it's written as

$$x=(2_{10})^4*(1011_2)+0010_2.$$

I use the index to indicate which base I use.

It's similar to saying

$$1234567 = 10^4*(123)+4567$$